# How to use arrow keys in vi in screen

Tags: vim, screen

I just started to use screen and I found it being very convenient to use. However, there's only one thing that bothers me is that screen unbind my arrow keys in vim.

Now, I understand that I should use hjklwf and such in vim, but as a typer that often make typing mistakes, i NEED the arrow keys in insertion mode.

So my question is, how do I configure vi or screen so that my arrow key will work?

```
cat > /dev/null
^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C     # UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT
```

Comment: `How to use arrow keys in vi?` -Don't!

Comment: then how do you fix something in insert mode? for example: "i want to fx ths linen but o domt want to prtss esc too much"

Comment: also, how do you navigate through the previous commands without using arrow keys?

Comment: "fix" means a few typos, in your example almost 90% words have problems. If I were you, I rewrite that line, less effort than "fix", no matter with/without arrows. . Or let vim's spell check fix for me. Pre/next command: since you asked this, I know that in terminal you don't use ctrl-p ctrl-n either. (emacs binds, which is default) In vim command mode, they work as well. "Insert" mode is called "Insert" because it is just for inserting text, not for navigation. Now you see why "Normal" mode is called "Normal". So my answer is still: **Don't**

Comment: I know it is not easy to forget arrows immediately. And I guess you don't agree with me. It's fine. if you love arrow keys, read this, it may help you:  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell

Comment: In normal mode, `ffai<Esc>fh.eexwwrifmsn'<Esc>ft;;;re`. Or any of a million variations. No arrows required. Once you get used to it, it is faster to edit outside of insert mode. As @Kent says, normal mode is called normal for a reason. In insert mode, Vim is just a weaksauce Notepad.

Comment: @Kent Thanks for the link! I'm still learning vim, and trying to not to use arrow keys. But sometimes I just need that arrow key to fix some code formatting issue (ie ascii art block comment :P) as I just dont know the proper command even i'm reading the manual. I agree with you on rewriting that example, it was a bad one D:

Comment: @Amadan OMG... this is cool..